# Python ArcGIS 10.0 Expanding select layer by location from point (walking selection)

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, select-by-location, arcview-3

I have an old ArcView 3 tool which I've been tasked with converting to Python. I'm breaking it down into stages, but there's a "walking selection" I can't trap.

To put the query in context, the user selects a site (point data) - selection A. All sites within X kilometres of selection A are then selected (selection B), then all sites within X of kilometres of selection B are selected, and so forth until no new selections are made.

I've tried to use a While... loop with a Get Count to no avail.  The problem I think is because the Get Count will always have a value, so I think I need to do something like Get Count <> Previous Get Count?

```
#Import ArcPy site package
import arcpy

# Overwrite files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

 try:
     # Make a feature layer with all the farms
     arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"shapefile.shp", "Farms")

    # Make a feature layer containing only the farm of interest
     arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"shapefile_select.shp","Farms_select")

    # Apply a selection to farms layer
    fcFarms = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management ("Farms","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE","Farms_select", "2000 Meters")

    # Apply a further selection to farms layer
    fcFarms2 = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Farms","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",fcFarms, "2000 Meters", "ADD_TO_SELECTION")

    while getCount > 0:
        fcFarms3 = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Farms","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", fcFarms2, "2000 Meters", "ADD_TO_SELECTION")
        fcFarms4 = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Farms","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", fcFarms3, "2000 Meters", "NEW_SELECTION")
        getCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fcFarms4))

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: What I think you want to do is after your first SelectByLocation do a arcpy.GetCount.  then for your while loop - do while newGetCount# > oldGetCount# and re-calculate it within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

before you while loop:

```
initial_getCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fcFarms2).getOutput(0))
getCount = initial_getCount + 1
```

then for you loop

```
while getCount > initial_getCount:
    if arcpy.Exists(fcFarms3):
        arcpy.Delete_management(fcFarms3)
    fcFarms3 = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Farms", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", fcFarms2, "2000 Meters", "ADD_TO_SELECTION")
    initial_getCount = getCount
    getCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fcFarms2).getOutput(0))
```

Comment: Thanks for advice @dklassen. I'd been trying something similar, but alas it doesn't work. It just runs the first two selections (before the loop) then stops.

Comment: Messed about a bit more and it turns out the if arcpy.Exists was causing the process to fail. Removed that line and it works. Thanks @dklassen.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, I modified your script. This will serve your requirement.

```
#Import ArcPy site package
import arcpy

# Overwrite files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def select_by_location(in_fc, target_fc, distance, selection_count=0):
    """ takes farms layer, selected layer, distance for selection"""
    selected_farms = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management (in_fc, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", target_fc, distance, "ADD_TO_SELECTION")
    # check the previous and current value should not same
    # if they are same that means no furthur selections has been made
    if arcpy.GetCount_management(selected_farms).getOutput(0) != selection_count:
        selection_count = arcpy.GetCount_management(selected_farms).getOutput(0)
        return select_by_location(in_fc, selected_farms, distance, selection_count)
    return selected_farms

def main():
    try:
        # Make a feature layer with all the farms
        farms = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"path_of_farms.shp", "farms")

        # Make a feature layer containing only the farm of interest
        farms_select = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"path_of_farm_interest.shp","farms_select")

        # Make selection on the farms_select layer
        farms_select = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(farms_select, "NEW_SELECTION", "Id = 0")

        # all_selected_farms contain all the selected farms within the given distance
        all_selected_farms = select_by_location(farms, farms_select, "80 Kilometer")

        # Save the all_selected_farms feature class to workspace
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(all_selected_farms , r"path_to_workspace if workspace is not defined earlier", "name of feature class")
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks @Surya. I can't seem to get this code to work. The main module works, but the select_by_location doesn't produce any selections. I presumed I had to change the in_fc etc, but I get a syntax error if I do that.

Comment: @Liam Mason: I changed the script for `select_by_location` function. Just for clarification `farms` is one feature class/shapefile and `farms_select` is another. I selected one feature from farms_select and performed the further selections on farms feature class. The result comes in `all_selected_farms`, which is in `in_memory`, so used `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` to save it to disk.  Hope this will work for you now. Otherwise drop a comment for further improvements. Thanks